# reading a text file horizontally and vertically in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

How do I do this problem?

Problem 13: Product of a Grid

Input File:  Prob13.in.txt

Output: Your output needs to be directed to stdout (i.e., using System.out.println())

Introduction

Everyone played connect four as a kid, right?  Well, you might call this problem “multiply four”.  Given a square grid of non-negative integers, you must find the greatest product of any four adjacent numbers in any direction (up, down, diagonally, left, right).  All numbers in the grid will be less than 100.

Program Input

The file Prob06.in.txt will contain a square grid of integers.  Numbers on the same line will be separated by a single space.

Example Input:

08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08

49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00

81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65

52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91

22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80

24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50

32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70

67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21

24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72

21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95

78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92

16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57

86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58

19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40

04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66

88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69

04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36

20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16

20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54

01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48

Program Output

Your program should print out the greatest product of any four adjacent numbers in the grid using the format shown below.  The solution is highlighted above for clarity.

Example Output:

Greatest product: 70600674

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788054/need-better-logic-for-tictactoe/29788374#29788374) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401)? These basically do a check for winning tic-tac-toe and connect four, but the concept is basically the same

Comment: Looks like a Project Euler problem... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110512/project-euler-13-large-sum

Answer (score 3):

You can save the data in a matrix made of arrays and then look the eight posible multiplication every number of the matrix has. Perform every multiplication and save it in an ArrayList, then you use sort metoid from Collections class. Something like this:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] matrix = new int[100][100];
    int j = 0;       
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    int third = 0;
    int fourth = 0;
    int fifth = 0;
    int sixth = 0;
    int seventh = 0;
    int eight = 0;
    String[] lineSplit = null;

    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\\\StackOverflow\\file.txt"));
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                lineSplit = line.split(" ");
                for(int i = 0; i < lineSplit.length; i++)
                {
                    matrix[j][i] = Integer.valueOf(lineSplit[i]);
                }
                j++;
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            int a = 0;
            for(int i = 0;i < j; i++)
            {
                for(int k = 0;k < lineSplit.length; k++)
                {
                    try{first = matrix[i][k] * matrix[i-1][k-1] * matrix[i-2][k-2] * matrix[i-3][k-3];}catch(Exception e){first = 0;}
                    try{second = matrix[i][k] * matrix[i-1][k] * matrix[i-2][k] * matrix[i-3][k];}catch(Exception e){second = 0;}
                    try{third = matrix[i][k] * matrix[i-1][k+1] * matrix[i-2][k+2] * matrix[i-3][k+3];}catch(Exception e){third = 0;}
                    try{fourth = matrix[i][k] * matrix[i][k+1] * matrix[i][k+2] * matrix[i][k+3];}catch(Exception e){fourth = 0;}
                    try{fifth = matrix[i][k] * matrix[i+1][k+1] * matrix[i+2][k+2] * matrix[i+3][k+3];}catch(Exception e){fifth = 0;}
                    try{sixth = matrix[i][k] * matrix[i+1][k] * matrix[i+2][k] * matrix[i+3][k];}catch(Exception e){sixth = 0;}
                    try{seventh = matrix[i][k] * matrix[i+1][k-1] * matrix[i+2][k-2] * matrix[i+3][k-3];}catch(Exception e){seventh = 0;}
                    try{eight = matrix[i][k] * matrix[i][k-1] * matrix[i][k-2] * matrix[i][k-3];}catch(Exception e){eight = 0;}

                    addNumber(first);
                    addNumber(second);
                    addNumber(third);
                    addNumber(fourth);
                    addNumber(fifth);
                    addNumber(sixth);
                    addNumber(seventh);
                    addNumber(eight);
                }
            }

            Collections.sort(numberList);
            System.out.println("The greatest: " + numberList.get(numberList.size()-1));
        }
        finally
        {
            br.close();
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static void addNumber(int number)
{
    if(number > 0)
    {
        numberList.add(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main concepts you are going to need to know to solve this problem are in my opinion as follows:
 Using two while loops(one nested), understanding loop conditionals, someReader.hasNextLine method, a two dimensional array, understanding of scoping for loops, a global Int variable row counter.

You are going to want to systematically parse the file using your file reader, I suggest you look up the the Scanner class.

1. Create a two dimensional array that will hold Int values(depending on if you have access to array lists or not the difficulty of this step will change).
2. Start with a building your first while loop. Add your conditional check using your reader to check if you have a .nextLine in the file. If false the loop should stop
3. Since the condition should have been true use the fileReader to use your .getNextLine method and save that value to a temporary String variable.
4. Take that String because a all String variables in java are object they have access to predefined inherited methods you can make use of. Make use of the .split() method.  We are going to need to make a temporary array to hold the split token(values) when we call the method. Created a counter for your second loop.

   ```
   String[] tokenHolder = savedStringLineFromBuffer.split(" ");
   Int counter = 0;
   ```
5. In a second while loop, check the length of the tokenHolder array. If the counter is less than the length of the array get current  token from tokenHolder using the value of your counter variable.

   ```
   String tempString ="";

   tokenHolder[counter] = tempString;

   int tempInt = Integer.parseInt(tempString);

   twoDimenArray[rowCounter][counter] = tempInt;
   ```

   This should add the current String variable as an integer into your 2D array.
6. After each iteration of each line you need to add +1 to the row counter.
   This should give you a full filled 2D array with the Int values for each value in the text file.
7. Without finishing the whole problem for you. You need loop each element of the 2D array and check the adjacent indexes. Get the first number, Each time you get the 4 Adjacent variables you want check to see if this number is greater than the previous. If so save it in place of the last.

   ```
   int valOne = twoDimenArray[row][col];
   int valTwo = twoDimenArray[row][col];
   int valThree = twoDimenArray[row][col];
   int valFour = twoDimenArray[row][col];
   ```

   And simply get the product, override the twoString method for your class and format the output.

Comment: All the values in that last code block are the exact same value. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to point out that he/she will need to use get independent items in the array which are adjacent from valOne. They need to be specified by row and col. They also need to be checked if they are null. I should have been a little more specific on that point, but I can tell this is a University comp-sci assignment. Most likely a first or second level course. Therefore, I don't want to solve the problem completely, and rob this person of the experience of learning problem solving skills.

Comment: If you look at the comment I left under the question, it's probably just a programming puzzle. Project Euler problem 13 is very similar to the question