# Tic Tac Toe Board - GetWinner

Tags: java

This is the method that gives the name of the winner (X or Y) of the tic tac toe board. If there's no winner, then it returns empty.

The player X goes first:

But in one particular situation, if doesn't work: 
x plays: 2,0
o plays: 1,0
x plays: 2,1
o plays: 1,1
x plays 2,2
(at which point 'X' should win but nothing happens)

o plays: 1,2
(at which point 'O' should win but nothing happens)

x plays any move

O is declared the winner.

I can't figure the bug out.

public static char checkWinner(char[][] array) {

```
// check for row winners
for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
  // if all three columns are the same then that player wins!
  if (array[row][0] == array[row][1] && array[row][1] == array[row][2]) {
    // return the winner!
    return array[row][0];
  }
}

// check for column winners
for (int col = 0; col < array.length; col++) {
  // if all three rows are the same then that player wins!
  if (array[0][col] == array[1][col] && array[1][col] == array[2][col]) {
    // return our winner!
    return array[0][col];
  }
}

// check for diag winners
if (array[0][0] == array[1][1] && array[1][1] == array[2][2]) {
  return array[0][0];
}

if (array[0][2] == array[1][1] && array[1][1] == array[2][0]) {
  return array[0][2];
}

// otherwise just return an empty character
return ' ';
```

}

If it helps, here is the whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create an empty board
    char[][] board = { { ' ', ' ', ' ' }, { ' ', ' ', ' ' }, { ' ', ' ', ' ' } };

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // start off with player 'X'
    char player = 'X';

    while (true) {
      printBoard(board);

      // ask the player for a location
      System.out.println("Welcome, player " + player);
      System.out.print("Enter a row: ");
      int row = input.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter a col: ");
      int col = input.nextInt();

      // check to see if this row is already taken
      if (board[row][col] != ' ') {
        System.out.println("\nThat spot is already taken!");
      } else {
        // otherwise assign the player's token to this spot
        board[row][col] = player;

        // check to see if someone won
        char testWinner = checkWinner(board);

        // do we have a winner?
        if (testWinner != ' ') {
          printBoard(board);
          System.out.println("We have a winner! " + testWinner);
          break;
        } else {
          // switch to the next player
          if (player == 'X') {
            player = 'O';
          } else {
            player = 'X';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static char checkWinner(char[][] array) {
    // check for row winners
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
      // if all three columns are the same then that player wins!
      if (array[row][0] == array[row][1] && array[row][1] == array[row][2]) {
        // return the winner!
        return array[row][0];
      }
    }

    // check for column winners
    for (int col = 0; col < array.length; col++) {
      // if all three rows are the same then that player wins!
      if (array[0][col] == array[1][col] && array[1][col] == array[2][col]) {
        // return our winner!
        return array[0][col];
      }
    }

    // check for diag winners
    if (array[0][0] == array[1][1] && array[1][1] == array[2][2]) {
      return array[0][0];
    }

    if (array[0][2] == array[1][1] && array[1][1] == array[2][0]) {
      return array[0][2];
    }

    // otherwise just return an empty character
    return ' ';
  }

  public static void printBoard(char[][] array) {
    System.out.println("\n----------");
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
      System.out.print("|");

      for (int col = 0; col < array.length; col++) {
        System.out.print(array[row][col] + " |");
      }

      System.out.println("\n----------");
    }

    System.out.println();
  }

}
```

Comment: You basically have a 2D matrix, what you need is some kind of method that can run from a given point through vertical, horizontal and two diagonals of the matrcies, maybe something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788054/need-better-logic-for-tictactoe/29788374#29788374)

Comment: code looks fine - i suspect the issue is with how you call this method, not with the method itself

Comment: @nhouser9 I just updated the post with the whole code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you see that all three chars of the current combination are the same you don't check whether it are three empty ones. In your example now it will give `' '` since the column with x = 0 is filled with `' '`s. This way of checking all combinations is also a bit long, I'd do it like this:

```
public static char checkWinner(char[][] array) {
    int[][] combinations = {
        {0, 1, 2},
        {3, 4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8},
        {0, 3, 6},
        {1, 4, 7},
        {2, 5, 8},
        {0, 4, 8},
        {2, 4, 6}
    };
    for (int[] co : combinations) {
        char[] cs = new char[] {
            array[co[0] % 3][co[0] / 3],
            array[co[1] % 3][co[1] / 3],
            array[co[2] % 3][co[2] / 3]
        };
        if (cs[0] != ' ' && cs[0] == cs[1] && cs[1] == cs[2]) {
            return cs[0];
        }
    }
    return ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checkWinner if conditions are ignoring the space character. And the row block returns on the first try since the top row is all spaces.