# Java action listener

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am making a tic tac toe game on Java using Netbeans. I hava a 3x3 board layout with buttons. When you click on a button, the button is disabled and the letter "X" or "O" appears as the label for the button. When I test my game out to get 3 "X's" in a row. It doesn't say I win until I click on another button. So it doesn't respond that I won until I click another button. Should I use a mouse released event instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gameOver` should be called last, as until you've updated the button you won't know if a win condition has been reached

You can also greatly reduce the code by using the source of the action

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object source = ae.getSource();
        JButton btn = (JButton)source;
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        btn.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 56));
        counter++;
        if(counter % 2 == 0 && counter < 10){
            btn.setText("O");
            gameText.setText("X's Turn!");                    
        } else {                       
            btn.setText("X");
            gameText.setText("O's Turn!");
        }           
        gameOver();
    }
}
```

Your `gameOver` check is somewhat limited, you could have a [look at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401) which is used for determining if a win condition in connect 4, but the idea is same.

If you prefer, [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788054/need-better-logic-for-tictactoe/29788374#29788374) applies the idea to tic tac toe

Comment: It should go in the middle, before announcing the next move, IMHO.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto You could have the result moved to the end of the loop, so you're not duplicating functionality, so if no win condition is determined, the users turn can be updated - I'm not overly keen on updating the `gameText` in the `if` statements, but I was trying to limit the number of modifications I was making to the over all code

Comment: wow @MadProgrammer  You just definitely saved my day man. It worked beautifully and my code looks much cleaner now. I will checkmark your answer in a few minutes.

Comment: and as for the gameOver method. I know what to do next to check if the columns and diagonals match. I just wanted to know if the response would work if I got 3 in a row.