# Need Help Getting 2 Player Functionality Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java, user-interface, tic-tac-toe

I need help getting my program to allow two human players play tic tac toe against each other. I have a lot of it done, just implementing another play and having it interact with the win condition is what I am having trouble with. I know my code is very lengthy, if anyone has any advice on making it more concise and efficient I would really appreciate it!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tic extends JFrame {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("TIC TAC TOE");   //Creates overall frame for the board. 
    JButton restart = new JButton("RESTART");   //Creates a button that allows the user to restart the game.
    JButton[][] b = new JButton[3][3]; //Initialized 2D array of b to mirror what the board layout would be.
    boolean occupied; //To check whether a cell is occupied or not
    boolean win = false; //To check whether the game is won or not.

     public static void main(String[] args){
          Tic t = new Tic();    //Ttt object is created to be initialized by the initialize method.
          t.init();
        }

     public Tic(){ //ttt gui constructor to set the parameters of the board.
         f.setSize(500, 450);
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         f.setVisible(true);
         f.setResizable(false);
        }

  public void winCondition(int r, int c){ //Method used to check whether someone has won using text of b ('X' or 'O').
            try {
            /* By checking all 3 cells to see if they equal the same text ('X' or 'O'), while also making sure they 
             * do not equal empty squares, this method is able to display whether or not a player has won.
             * 
             * This same method of checking for a winner is done for every possible way of winning the game.
             * (8 Possibilities)
             */
            if ((b[0][2].getText().equals(b[1][2].getText()) && (b[1][2].getText().equals(b[2][2].getText())
                && (b[2][2].getText().equals(b[0][2].getText()) && (!(b[1][2].getText()).equals("")))))){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Player: " + b[0][2].getText() + " won the game!");
                win = true; 
                }

            else if ((b[0][1].getText().equals(b[1][1].getText()) && (b[1][1].getText().equals(b[2][1].getText()) 
                     && (b[2][1].getText().equals(b[0][1].getText()) && (!(b[1][1].getText().equals(""))))))){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Player: " + b[1][1].getText() + " won the game!");
                win = true;
                }

            else if ((b[0][0].getText().equals(b[1][0].getText()) && (b[1][0].getText().equals(b[2][0].getText()) 
                    && (b[2][0].getText().equals(b[0][0].getText()) && (!(b[1][0].getText().equals(""))))))){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Player: " + b[1][0].getText() + " won the game!");
                win = true;
                }

            else if ((b[2][0].getText().equals(b[2][1].getText()) && (b[2][1].getText().equals(b[2][2].getText())
                    && (b[2][2].getText().equals(b[2][0].getText()) && (!(b[2][1].getText().equals(""))))))){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Player: " + b[2][1].getText() + " won the game!");
                win = true;
                }

            else if ((b[1][0].getText().equals(b[1][1].getText()) && (b[1][1].getText().equals(b[1][2].getText())
                    && (b[1][2].getText().equals(b[1][0].getText()) && (!(b[1][1].getText().equals(""))))))){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Player: " + b[1][1].getText() + " won the game!");
                win = true;
                }

            else if ((b[0][0].getText().equals(b[0][1].getText()) && (b[0][1].getText().equals(b[0][2].getText()) 
                    && (b[0][2].getText().equals(b[0][0].getText()) && (!(b[0][1].getText().equals(""))))))){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Player: " + b[0][1].getText() + " won the game!");
                win = true;
                }

            else if ((b[0][0].getText().equals(b[1][1].getText()) && (b[1][1].getText().equals(b[2][2].getText())
                    && (b[2][2].getText().equals(b[0][0].getText()) && (!(b[1][1].getText().equals(""))))))){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Player: " + b[1][1].getText() + " won the game!");
                win = true;
                }

            else if ((b[0][2].getText().equals(b[1][1].getText()) && (b[1][1].getText().equals(b[2][0].getText())
                   && (b[2][0].getText().equals(b[0][2].getText()) && (!(b[1][1].getText().equals(""))))))){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Player: " + b[0][2].getText() + " won the game!");
                win = true;
                }
            }catch(Exception e) { //Catch statement to determine whether or not the game was a draw.
                win = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "It's a draw!");
            }
        }


  public void init(){ //Method used to initialize the game board
      JPanel grandPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); //Grand Panel to add additional panels to.
      grandPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); //Button Panel to add the Restart button to.
      buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
      buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      restart.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      restart.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      buttonPanel.add(restart, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3)); //Board Panel to display the actual game.
      boardPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

      f.add(grandPanel);

      grandPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); //This allows me to position the buttons above the game    
      grandPanel.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      restart.addActionListener(new myActionListener());

      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){   //This nested for loop is how each ttt cell is given an  action listener and added to buttons array.                    
          for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
              b[i][j] = new JButton();              
              b[i][j].setText("");
              b[i][j].setVisible(true);
              b[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
              boardPanel.add(b[i][j]); //Adds the buttons to the board
              b[i][j].addActionListener(new myActionListener());
         }
      }
    }

private class myActionListener implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
       /* Checks the source of which button the user clicks
        * then the text is changed to X or O and the win condition
        * is called.  
        */
       if(a.getSource() == b[0][0]){
           b[0][0].setText("X");
           b[0][0].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
           b[0][0].setEnabled(false);
           winCondition(0,0);
         } 
       else if(a.getSource() == b[0][1]){
           b[0][1].setText("X");
           b[0][1].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
           b[0][1].setEnabled(false);
           winCondition(0,1);
         } 
       else if(a.getSource() == b[0][2]){
          b[0][2].setText("X");  
          b[0][2].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
          b[0][2].setEnabled(false);
          winCondition(0,2);
        } 
       else if(a.getSource() == b[1][0]){
          b[1][0].setText("X");
          b[1][0].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
          b[1][0].setEnabled(false);
          winCondition(1,0);
        }
       else if(a.getSource() == b[1][1]){
          b[1][1].setText("X");
          b[1][1].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
          b[1][1].setEnabled(false); 
          winCondition(1,1);
        } 
       else if(a.getSource() == b[1][2]){
         b[1][2].setText("X");
         b[1][2].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
         b[1][2].setEnabled(false);
         winCondition(1,2);
        } 
       else if(a.getSource() == b[2][0]){
         b[2][0].setText("X");
         b[2][0].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
         b[2][0].setEnabled(false);
         winCondition(2,0);
        }
       else if(a.getSource() == b[2][1]){
         b[2][1].setText("X");
         b[2][1].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
         b[2][1].setEnabled(false);
         winCondition(2,1);
        }
       else if(a.getSource() == b[2][2]){
         b[2][2].setText("X");
         b[2][2].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
         b[2][2].setEnabled(false);
         winCondition(2,2);
        }
       else if(a.getSource() == restart){
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
               for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                   b[i][j].setText(""); 
                   b[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                   win = false;
                }
             }
           }
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what this means `implementing another play`

Comment: You have a lot of duplicated logic. Instead of having all those `if` statements, you can extract the coordinates of the action to x/y variables, and act on those variables without knowing the exact value.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: *"I know my code is very lengthy, if anyone has any advice on making it more concise and efficient I would really appreciate it!"* - Don't rely on the state of your UI components to make determinations about the state of the game - instead, separate the logic and state into a separate class or classes (ie a model/controller) and use the UI to represent that state

Comment: You can also simplify you "win" condition using a "search" style algorithm, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788054/need-better-logic-for-tictactoe/29788374#29788374) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401)

Answer (score 1):

> just implementing another play and having it interact with the win condition

Based on your available code, you're only playing with `X`.  What you need is some means to know which player's turn it is (ie `O` or `X`).

The simple solution would be to have an instance field which represented the current player (ie `O` or `X`) and in the `ActionListener`, use it instead of the hard coded `X`.

This would mean that you're "win" check would need to be able to support a variable player and check for the various possible win conditions for that player.

> I know my code is very lengthy, if anyone has any advice on making it more concise and efficient I would really appreciate it!

Don't rely on the state of your UI components to make determinations about the state of the game - instead, separate the logic and state into a separate class or classes (ie a model/controller) and use the UI to represent that state

You can also simplify your "win" condition using a "search" style algorithm, for example:

- [Need better logic for TicTacToe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788054/need-better-logic-for-tictactoe/29788374#29788374)
- [Connect 4 check for a win algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd like to point out is that since your class extends JFrame you don't need a variable that is a JFrame (unless it's a different JFrame than the main one). This means in your init method you can remove all f.

The second thing I'd like to point out is that in your method win condition, you have 2 unused parameters r and c;

In order to implement a 2 player setup, you need to have a variable, preferably a boolean, that keeps track of which player's turn it is. (With the boolean true would be p1's turn and false would be p2's turn) Then based on this boolean you can decide to draw an X or an O. From there your winCondition method should take care of the rest!

Let me know if you have any issues whilst trying to implement this!

Comment: I got it working, thank you for the advice! Much appreciated!

Comment: Awesome! Happy Coding!