# stuck with this word searching program

Tags: java, iteration, character, wordsearch

im making a word search program, the grid is 10 x 10 and all the letters are in a Char[][] array.
There is a words list too.

```
    public static void find(){

    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File(WORD_FILE));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();


    while (input.hasNextLine()){
        words.add( input.nextLine());
    }
    input.close();
    initgrid(); 
    for (char[] a : grid){
        String c =String.valueOf(a);
         for (String s : words){
            if (s.contains(c)){
           // what can i do now?      
             }
    }
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to how i can make the program iterate through each letter of the grid, and look for the words from the word list...it should be able to read words horizontally, vertically and diagonally.

here is my InitGrid() method which opens the grid file and assigns each character to a char[][] array.

```
 public static char[][] initGrid(){


    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File(GRID_FILE));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] tmp = new String[10];
    int c = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()){
        tmp[c++]=input.nextLine();
    }
    input.close();


    for (int b = 0; b<tmp.length;b++){
        for (int j= 0; j<tmp[b].length();j++){

            grid[b][j] = tmp[b].charAt(j);

        }
    }

    return grid;
```

Comment: I little bit of lateral thinking, but [Need better logic for TicTacToe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788054/need-better-logic-for-tictactoe/29788374#29788374) and [Connect 4 check for a win algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401) demonstrate a basic concept of searching a 2D matrix - albeit for like elements.  The point is though, given a start point, the algorithms can walk in all eight directions looking for matches.

Comment: It would require a little more work to make it search for the characters of a `String`, but it's a basic step in the direction